# Can we add the zero vector to a scalar, and get the scalar back?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

$\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are vectors.
$\vec{0}$ is the 0 vector.

Please consider the calculation:

$$(\vec{A} \cdot{} \vec{B}) + \vec{0}$$

Is this calculation valid? If so, what does it yield?

$(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B})$ of course gives a scalar. However, $\vec{0}$ is a vector, and I think we cannot add a scalar to a vector.

Comment: You're correct that the expression you're asking about is undefined because it doesn't make sense to add a vector to a scalar.

Comment: In some branches of math it is common to use the notation $\mathbb{v}+c$, where $\mathbb{v}$ is a vector, and $c$ is a scalar, to indicate that you add $c$ to all coordinates of $\mathbb{v}$. But it is just a matter of notational convention that exists in some areas.

Answer (score 0):

This operation is not usually defined. If you see the definition of a vector space, it doesn't consist of any property of addition between a scalar and a vector. I mean if $(V,+,*)$ is a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$. So, two operations are defined as follows: $+: V \times V \to V$ and $ *: V \times \mathbb{F} \to V$. But there is no definition for $+ : V \times \mathbb{F} \to (\mathbb{F} ~\text{or}~ V)$. But you can define such operations, that is, for example, $+: V \times \mathbb{F} \to V$ defined as $+(v,c) = v + c = (v_{1}+c, v_{2}+c, \cdots,v_{n}+c)$, if $V$ is a $n$ dimensional vector space, and $v = (v_{1}, v_{2}, \cdots, v_{n})$.